# UITableViewCell no userInteraction but on cell.accessoryView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableViewCell with a UISwitch in accessoryView. I don't want that blue background if someone selected it. There fore i used

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

but then the whole cell isnt accessable so i tried that

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
cell.accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

i think this wont work because cell is the parent of the accessoryView. but how can i manage this issue ? A hint in the right direction would be great.

Simon

Here is the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"dasda";
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

UISwitch *mySwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
mySwitch.tag = row;
[cell addSubview:mySwitch];
cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
cell.accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView setOn: YES];
[(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

return cell;
```

Comment: +1 for the "genius and nerds"! They are often close to each other these two. :)

Comment: As the person who answered this question, I am wondering if I am a genius or a nerd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

You also have the option of using this in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
[table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```